# What is the rationale behind the growing policy of the SparseArrayCompat in Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-support-library, sparse-matrix

The `SparseArrayCompat` class in the Android support library is a lightweight implementation of a map using arrays.  Like many container implementations using arrays, it has a growing policy that ensures the array capacity is enough to hold all elements.  In the `SparseArrayCompat` implementation, the growing policy is expressed in `ContainerHelpers.idealByteArraySize()`, which goes like this:

```
public static int idealByteArraySize(int need) {
    for (int i = 4; i < 32; i++)
        if (need <= (1 << i) - 12)
            return (1 << i) - 12;


    return need;
}
```

It appears to choose a closest power of 2 that is larger than or equal to the needed capacity.  What I don't get is the subtraction of 12 in the return statement.  The `-12` term in the `if` condition seems to be arbitrarily extra space wanted in case if the needed capacity grows in the near future, which makes sense, but the return statement gets rid of that extra space.  Shouldn't the return statement just return `(1 << i)` without the subtraction?

I would love to hear if anyone can help to explain this to me.  I can't help but feel this tickle around my back without understanding why.

References:

- SparseArrayCompat https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/util/SparseArrayCompat.java
- ContainerHelpers https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/util/ContainerHelpers.java

Comment: Most likely you won't get one straight forward answer or one definitive reason why this method calculates the size like it does. Things like this are mostly determined experimentally - in other words just testing what works best. You can find equally philosophical algorithms or constants in most other `Collection` implementations and also in most thread pools or similar things.

Answer (score 2):

Here's [an old comment](http://osxr.org/android/source/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/util/ArrayUtils.java) about it:

```
// it looks like right now objects want to be powers of 2 minus 8
// and the array size eats another 4 bytes
```

Perhaps it was trying to have the entire container object fit perfectly within a 2^n allocation?  If so, it doesn't seem like it'll work for the `SparseArrayCompat` class because of the `mGarbage` member...